# How do I use the control callback when creating a simple dashboard plugin

Tags: widgets, dashboard, callbacks

On this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_dashboard_widget

The function **wp_add_dashboard_widget** is described.

It states:

```
wp_add_dashboard_widget($widget_id, $widget_name, $callback, $control_callback = null)
```

How do you use the $control_callback, properly? I am completeley stuck, as I have defined it but cannot use it.

I need to create a form within this widget which is why I am using the control_callback.

**EDIT:** as a side note I am using Wordpress 3 and Multisite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution : hover on the title bar of your widget, then click **configure**

Don't ask me why this works like this but it does.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to handle form/input data? If not, then you can omit the `$control_Callback`, and simply use the `$callback` in order to display content.

Comment: yes, see edit: I do need input data, hence why I am using the control_callback...